# How do I plot a grid with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

[image]

But I need dashed boxes and blue color (better semi transparent):/ Too new to tikz, no Idea how to embed grid into labled axis..

Comment: Hi! There are plenty of examples of grids in the TikZ manual.  Can you adapt one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read first tutorials in `TikZ` documentation and try to understand this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily]
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \ni using {int(\i*2+\j)}] in {0,1}
        \node[draw, dashed, fill=blue!30, opacity=.5, minimum size=1cm] (\ni) at (\i,\j) {\ni};}
\draw[->] (0.south west)--++(90:2.5) node[above]{x\_domains=(0y)};
\draw[->] (0.south west)--++(0:4.5) node[right]{y\_domains=(0x)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]